# What is the right term, properties panel or shelf?

Tags: interface

[image]

I heard it being called ["viewport properties panel"](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/workflows/multiview/usage.html)

even though [panels](https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/editors/panels.html) are the things inside the shelf.

I heard it being called the ["tool shelf"](https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/editors/panels.html)

But I get the feeling that tool shelf refers to only the (t) shortcut shelf that appears to the left side.

Maybe the right term is "properties shelf"?

Comment: to me iNformation panel or property following the menu (but I don't think this is good here)

Comment: but the manual says : Panels are collapsible sections within "regions" to help organize the interface. https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/editors/panels.html

Comment: I read a little further down the page and its called "the properties shelf"

Comment: ok, but in fact what is the aim of your question ? I mean N for this panel, and T for the tools one... but what more with all that for your question ?

Comment: im thinking of editing the manual because when I was reading here: https://www.blender.org/manual/render/workflows/multiview/usage.html and it said: "You can toggle this and other display settings in the Stereoscopy tab of the viewport properties panel." I was hella confused were those settings were. I think I will change the words "viewport properties panel" to "viewport properties shelf".

Comment: And change "Stereoscopy tab" to "Stereoscopy panel"

Comment: I don't know what your question is... but if it is to stereoscopy, you may edit it to explain that a bit more, don't you think ?

Comment: my question is on proper terminology because I think the manual got some of it wrong.

Comment: Maybe this kind of subject is to be discuss on the meta (is BSE the good place to talk about that). I am not sure, but have a try, or search for this kind of subject. And surely Blender's documentation can be edited by users (I don't know how but surely you can participate).

Comment: I know how to do it, its easy. But I dont know everything so I want a second opinion before changing it. You say BSE is a good place for that?

Comment: No, I meant asking on meta if BSE is a good place to ask that. Or directly ask on meta about it

Comment: thanks for the heads up, I will go there when I have a  question on documentation.

Comment: I believe @lemon was saying that you should ask on the meta whether questions regarding errors in documentation are *good* questions for this site, not that you should ask documentation questions there.

Comment: o i c http://ct.fra.bz/ol/fz/sw/i52/5/3/26/frabz-of-course-that-makes-sense-320044.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender's naming scheme is quite confusing, especially since many creators (including me) of tutorials and howto videos don't use them consistently (and there's a reason for this mess).  So let's break it down a little.

The [Blender Manual introduction](https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/introduction.html) says that Blender's UI can be broken up into the Main Window, which contains one or more Areas with each Area containing an Editor. Editors usually have a Header and one or more Regions. Regions then contain Panels.

According to the Manual the highlighted area in your screenshot is called "Properties Region". It shows all properties of your currently selected object(s) and lets you also edit some additional properties for your scene. Some of them could also be changed within the Properties Editor (I'm trying to stay with the terminology here...)

[image: properties... properties everywhere!]

This seems a little absurd but it immediately makes sense if you switch the 3D View to fullscreen area (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>).

The reason why Blender's naming scheme is still confusing is that even Blender itself calls it Panel.

[image]

Comment: Over here its called the properties shelf: https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/editors/panels.html   But over here its called the Properties Region : https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/introduction.html#regions  And in Blender its called a  "panel" as you pointed out... https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/AAEAAQAAAAAAAAJQAAAAJGY4OTU1NDAzLTg2ODYtNGNmNC04YjMwLTI0MTU0MGZmOTdmNw.png

Comment: do you think it should be called "properties shelf"? I think that makes the most sense, no?

Comment: I'd stay with properties panel. I for myself stopped using the term shelf around the time of Blender 2.59. If they have the <kbd>Key</kbd> tags on that wiki, maybe that would be enough?

Comment: so this page is wrong in saying: "Panels are collapsible sections within regions to help organize the interface. They are heavily used in the Properties Editor but also appear elsewhere (For example: in the Tool Shelf or the Properties Shelf, available in some editors)." https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/editors/panels.html