# How to 'lock in' favourite 'panels'

Tags: edit-mode

Sorry if this has been asked before but I could not find a previously asked question which appeared to be the same.

I have 'lost' the 'transform' panel where the dimensions of a mesh object can be changed. Well its still there but everytime I restart Blender I have to 'drag' it out only to have it 'disappear' the next time O start Blender.   Also I thought that there was a shortcut key (T?) which would make it reappear which doesn't seem to work (and I tried shift T, Ctrl T as well as other keyboard keys. I also looked in the manual and in Youtube.

Here is an image with the transform panel displayed after I 'dragged' it out.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/59150/what-is-the-right-term-properties-panel-or-shelf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that’s called the 3D View *Properties Panel*. Regardless of the name, it appears when you press <kbd>N</kbd>.

In any case, I would go to menu *File* -> *Defaults* -> *Save startup file*.

Comment: Thanks. That must be the only key I did not press in an attempt to display the panel.  Lastly I assume that the panel display (option) gets stored with a model when you save model? I have noticed that if I open a previous project it displays the transform panel but if I start from scratch then the panel is not automatically displayed.

Comment: As @TheLabCat suggests, open Blender with the default cube, open the propeties panel with 'N' and save your startup file via the File > Defaults > Save Startup File menu. You can also set up things like the renderer that you use most frequently (Cycles or Eevee) and other settings before you save the startup file and Blender will start with those set as default.

Comment: Thanks. That is good to know.